# Append linked list to the end of another

Tags: c, list, merge

im trying to insert one list in the end of another
with this code:

```
typedef struct Element
{
    int vKey;
    char vInfo[30];
    struct Element *pNext;

} tsElement;

typedef struct
{
    tsElemento *pFirst;
    int vLength;

} tsLDSE;

void Unir(tsLDSE *pListIn, tsLDSE *pListOut) 
{
    tsElement *pElementOut;

    pElementOut = pListOut->pFirst;

    while (pElementOut != NULL)
    {
        pElementOut = pElemenoOut->pNext;
    }

    pElementOut = pListIn->pFirst;
    pListOut->vLength = pListOut->vLength + pListIn->vLength ;
}
```

i checked printing the adresses, pElementoOut is really the end of the first list and is poiting to NULL, then it receives the fisrt adress of the second list, but when i print it out it only prints the first list and i can't figure out why.

Comment: You need `pElemenoOut->pNext = pListIn->pFirst` *before* `pElemenoOut` is `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but i don't get why is that
since pElementOut is pPrevious->pNext and is null
why can't i just pElementOut = pListIn->First

Comment: `pElementOut` is a local variable that has the *same value* as `pPrevious->pNext`, but `pElementOut` is **not** `pPrevious->pNext`.

Comment: LInked, list so therefore no debugging done, so DCV.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `Unir` only adds the length of the input list to the length of the output list.

This loop:

```
while (pElementOut != NULL)
{
    pElementOut = pElemenoOut->pNext;
}
```

Only gets `pElementOut` to be NULL.

In addition, when you write `pElementOut = pListIn->pFirst;`, all you change is the local variable `pElementOut`.

What you want to do instead is this:

```
while (pElementOut->pNext != NULL)
{
    pElementOut = pElementOut->pNext;
}

pElementOut->pNext = pListIn->pFirst;
```

This puts the first element of pListIn at the end of the last element of pListOut.

Also, add a NULL check at the beginning of your function! You can easily get a NULL pointer dereference there if you aren't careful.